# Conditional expectation of the smaller uniform random variable

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation

Suppose $U_1, U_2 \sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$ and both random variables are independent. I want to compute $E[U_1 \mid U_1 < U_2]$. I think the correct ansewr is

$$
E[U_{1}\mid U_{1}<U_{2}]=E[U_{1}\mid U_{1}=\min\{U_{1},U_{2}\}]=E[\min\{U_{1},U_{2}\}]=\int_{0}^{1}2(1-x)xdx=\frac{1}{3}.
$$

But, I was wondering why the following reasoning leads to incorrect solution. If we fix $U_2 =u$, then $E[U_1\mid U_1 <u]=u/2$. Each $u$ happens equally likely, i.e., $U_2\sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$, so $E[U_1\mid U_1 < U_2] = E[U_2]/2=1/4$. Or, more formally,
$$
E[U_{1}\mid U_{1}<U_{2}]=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{u}\frac{x}{u}dxdu=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u}{2}du=\frac{1}{4}.
$$

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since $U_2\sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$

This is the mistake.

$U_2$ corresponds to $y$ when you pick a random point $(x,y)$ in the $x$-$y$ plane in the triangular region bound by $x\geq0$, $x\leq y$, and $y\leq 1$. It is easy to see that the distribution of $y$ is not $\mathcal{U}[0,1]$.

Comment: I see graphically how the joint distribution looks like (uniform over a rectangle), but I do not understand why "the distribution of $y$ is not $\mathcal{U}[0,1]$. In the rectangle $[0,1]^2$, if I fix $y=1$, I get $(1/2,1)$ as $E[x\mid x<1]. Repeating this for each $y$, I get a line $y=2x$ in $[0,1]^2$. The middle point of the line is $(1/4,1/2)$, which is basically the graphical argument of my second reasoning. Again I do not see why this is incorrect.

Comment: It is a triangle, not a rectangle.

Comment: Yes the joint distribution $(U_1, U_2) | U_1 < U_2$ is a triangle and the marginal distribution of $U_2|U_1 < U_2$ is $2x$, which is precisely the pdf of $\max(U_1,U_2)$. But I'm still not sure what is wrong with the following intuition: For each $U_2$, $E[U_1| U_1 < U_2]=U_2/2$. Each $U_2$ happens equally likely, so $E[U_1| U_1 < U_2]=1/4$

Comment: It’s unclear to me which part you are confused about. Are you unclear why every point in the triangle is equally likely? Or are you unclear why every y value within the triangle is not equally likely? Or something else?

Comment: I am confused as to what is wrong with the following intuition. For $U_2=1$, $E[U_1 | U_1 < 1]=0.5$. For $U_2 = 0.9$, $E[U_1 | U_1 < 0.9] = 0.45$, etc. When I pick $U_2$, there is no restriction, so $E[U_1 | U_1 < U_2] = \int_0^1 E[U_1 | U_1 < u] du$. I guess you are saying that when I pick $U_2$, I should pick according to the distribution $U_2 = \max(U_1,U_2)$, but I am not sure why this is. For any $U_2=u$ that I pick without restriction, I can compute $E[U_1 | U_1 < u]$, and I am just averaging $U_2$

Comment: Let’s consider two ways to pick a random point from a triangle. One option is to pick uniformly randomly. The second option is to pick a random height uniformly, and then to pick a point uniformly randomly from the segment consisting of points of that chosen height. Are the two options equivalent? How would you convince someone that answers incorrectly that they are wrong?

Comment: Ah now I see that when picking the height, I should consider the marginal distribution of it, because the triangle is the goal, thank you